# Why doesn't scrapy elasticsearch pipeline work in combination with images pipeline

Tags: scrapy

I am using the images pipeline with scrapy.

The items.py file defines image_urls = Field() and image_paths = Field()

When in debug mode, both fields are populated properly according to what is sent to stout.

At the same time my settings.py contains a second pipeline that sends all field data to elasticsearch. Then, for some reason the image_paths field is not included in the the item[] dict.

I have no clue what the problem is.. maybe it is interesting to note that image_urls is populated from within the spider whereas image_paths is populated from the images pipeline in the process_item() method.

The order of both pipelines is defined in a way that the images pipeline (numerical parameter "100") is processed before the elasticsearch pipeline (numerical parameter "200").

So the question is why doesn't scrapy elasticsearch pipeline work in combination with images pipeline the way I implemented it?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code ?

Comment: Also post the link to the elasticsearch pipeline you are using.